# Complex Sine is Unbounded

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I was trying to think of a proof that $\text{sin}(z)$ is unbounded without using Liouville's theorem.

Suppose it is bounded. Then in particular, it is bounded around for $|z|$ large. Then $\text{sin}(1/z)$ is bounded for $|z|$ small i.e. around $0$. So by Riemann's theorem for removable singularities, $0$ is a removable singularity of $\text{sin}(1/z)$, so it is holomorphically extendable to $\mathbb{C}$. But this implies $\underset{z\to 0}{\text{lim}} \ \text{sin}(1/z)$ exists. But $\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}} \ \text{sin}(1/x)$, where $x\in\mathbb{R}$, DNE.

Does this look correct?

Comment: $\sin(ix)=i\sinh(x)$ so like no way its bounded LOL

Comment: It seems correct to me, but I would have just used the fact that $\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ and then set $z=-it$ and let $t$ get big.

Comment: for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ consider $2\cdot \sin(-ix)=2\cdot \frac{e^{i\cdot(- ix)}-e^{-i\cdot(- i x)}}{2}=e^{x}-e^{-x}\geq e^x$ which is unbounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. If $n\in\mathbb N$, then
$$
\sin (-in)=\frac{1}{2i}(e^n-e^{-n}).
$$